# Copy multiple numpy arrays(4,1) into a single numpy array(4,n)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Im taking an input processing it and storing it in a column format(4 * 1 array) and then putting this in a (4 * n np.zero array)..looping this to get n inputs

```
import numpy as np
l= int(input("enter the no. of elements"))
print ("enter the co-ordinates (X Y Z)-space seperated ")
i=0
inpf=np.zeros([4,(l)])
while(i<l):
    inp1=np.array(input().split(" "))
    inp2=[int(j) for j in inp1]
    inp3=np.append(inp2,[1],axis=0)
    inp=np.atleast_2d(inp3).T
    inpf[:,i]=inp
    i=i+1

print(inf)
```

This code isn't working (error- inpf[:,i]=inp
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,1) into shape (4,))

How do I solve this error ? How do I make the code more
space efficient ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what results you are looking for but removing the `.T` will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks.. Could you tell me why that .T was causing the error ..

Comment: It transposes the array https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html. `shape(1,4)` turns to `shape(4,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a simpler list approach

```
inp1=input().split(" ")
inp2=[int(j) for j in inp1]
inp2.append(1)
inpf[:,i]=inp2
```